# Issue with website on Ipad - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing an online store.

My client wants it to have a correct appearance on an iPad. The problem is that when it loads in landscape, the website is not centered and displays a "white bar" on it's right.

I've been going around this for a couple of days now, and still haven't found any solution for this problem. I think this is only a CSS problem but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Or, look at making your site responsive to take into account actual devide widths.

Comment: It still has the white bar on the right, but now it loads fullscreen just the way i wanted! Thank you very much! I didn't know that meta tag, but as far i can see it sets the width as the device-width and also defines the scales... Is this a must have for every website?

Comment: @user1776702 - Worth a read: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

Comment: @user1776702 Also, should you choose to go the responsive route (which I would 100% suggest you do), this is a great source of information: http://bradfrost.github.com/this-is-responsive/resources.html

Comment: Thank you for everything @Alan Shortis!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using media queries? Your website isnt responsive from what ive tested. Media queries will allow you to define how the max looks on different sized screens.

http://mediaqueri.es/

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

For example for an iPhone 4

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {


}
```